# Extract method and parameter from Java code

Tags: regex, perl, bash, awk, sed

I've got text of the form:

> Class inType = ReflectionUtils.getClass(c.getString("in-type"));

Based on getString("in-type") I need to turn this into:

> String in-type

getString may be replaced with getDouble and getBoolean

i.e. there is a method call in set {getString, getDouble,getBoolean} which is followed by a curved bracket, a quoted string and then closing curved bracket.

There may be more than one string on a line (so looking purely for "" is not going to work), and there may be more than one getString... etc method on one line.

Sometimes, there may be a new lines after the getString and the string

How would you go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of Perl to end my day:

```
perl -ne '/get(String|Double|Boolean)\("(.*?)"\)/ && print "$1 $2\n"' <input file>
```

The -n causes perl to loop over the file line by line, and the regex looks for a couple of capture groups before printing out those groups from any lines it matches. This doesn't cope with the edge case of newlines after `getString`.

Comment: Very nice! I think though maybe the print should be `print $2 . " " . $3 ...` to get the output like `String in-type` instead of `getString in-type`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways:

1. `grep` and `sed`

   ```
   grep -oP 'get\K(String|Boolean|Double)\("[^"]+' file | sed 's/("/ /'
   ```

   The `-o` means "print only the matched string", the `-P` turns on Perl COmpatible Regular Expressions. The `\K` discards anything matched up to that point. The final `sed` just fixed the formatting.
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" while /get(String|Boolean|Double)\("([^"]+)/g ' file
   ```

   Very similar to @chooban's answer but can deal with multiple occurrences on the same line.